# Plot a boolean/qualitative table with R

Tags: r, plot, legend, symbols, categorical

I am looking for a way to create a table in R for categorical data. The elements in the table should be symbols, and these symbols should be displayed in a legend.

[This table from the ICILS 2018 report is to illustrate the kind of table I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsjjN.jpg)

For example, I have this data frame that can be used to make a similar table:

```
      Country School.level Local.authority.level Country.level
1    BE-fr          Yes                   Yes            No
2    BE-nl          Yes                   Yes            No
3       CY          Yes                   Yes           Yes
4       EL           No                    No           Yes
5       ES          Yes                    No           Yes
6       FI          Yes                   Yes           Yes
7       FR          Yes                   Yes           Yes
8       HR          Yes                   Yes           Yes
9       HU          Yes                    No           Yes
10      IE          Yes                    No            No
11      PT          Yes                   Yes           Yes
12      RS           No                    No           Yes
13      SI          Yes                    No           Yes
14      SK          Yes                    No           Yes
```